# If $U_0 = 0$ and $U_n=\sqrt{U_{n-1}+(1/2)^{n-1}}$, then $U_n < U_{n-1}+(1/2)^n$ for $n > 2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality

Letting $$U_n=\sqrt{U_{n-1}+(1/2)^{n-1}}$$ where $U_0=0$, prove that:

$$U_n < U_{n-1}+(1/2)^n$$ where $n>2$

Comment: @Ju'x Thanks. But $(1/2)^n-1$ might read $(1/2)^{n-1}$, otherwise $U_1$ is undefined.

Comment: @Babak: There are at least 15 question edited by you on the front page. Others may disagree, but I don't think it is a good idea to do that, unless you have a very good reason for all those edits.

Comment: @Chebli Several people now tried to make your question readable. Unfortunately the current version asks to show something which is obviously false ($U_0=0$ and $U_1=1$ hence $U_1\gt U_0+1/2$). If only by correction, it is high time that you indicate what the question really is.

Comment: You added the condition `n>2` to the question. There is not anymore obvious counterexamples, as far as I can see. Now, the next level: what did you try to solve the thing? (And why do you think it is true?)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Thanks for noting me that. Yes, you are right. :) Maybe it was not appropriate here. Honestly, there was not a certain reason for that. Thanks and apology.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a useful factoid:

> For every $x\geqslant1$ and $y\gt0$, $\sqrt{x+2y}\lt x+y$.

Now, apply this to your setting. First note that $U_n\geqslant1$ implies $U_{n+1}\geqslant1$. Since $U_1=1$, this proves that $U_n\geqslant1$ for every $n\geqslant1$. Then, choosing $n\geqslant2$, $x=U_{n-1}$ and $y=1/2^n$, the factoid yields $U_n\lt U_{n-1}+1/2^n$, as desired.

Finally the result holds for every $n\geqslant2$ (and not only $n\gt2$).

Can you prove the factoid above?

Comment: (x+2y)-(x+y)^2=x+2y-x^2-2xy-y^2=x(1-x)+2y(1-x)-y^2<0 since all terms are negative

Comment: Indeed. $ $ $ $

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $ U_1 = 1,\ U_2 = \sqrt{1+(1/2)}> 1 $ and $ U_n > 1 $ implies $U_{n+1} > 1$ using the recursion, hence inductively $ U_n > 1 $ for all $ n>1 $.
Now rationalizing suitably you will find 
$$ U_k - U_{k-1} = \sqrt{U_{k-1} + (1/2)^{k-1}}-\sqrt{U_{k-2}+(1/2)^{k-2}} \\
 = \frac{U_{k-1}-U_{k-2} -(1/2)^{k-1}}{\sqrt{U_{k-1} + (1/2)^{k-1}}+\sqrt{U_{k-2}+(1/2)^{k-2}}} < \frac{U_{k-1}-U_{k-2}}{U_k + U_{k-1}} < \frac{U_{k-1}-U_{k-2}}{2} $$
So you have $ U_1-U_0 = 1 $ and for all $ k > 1\ $
$ \frac{U_k-U_{k-1}}{U_{k-1}-U_{k-2}} < (1/2) $ So multiplying terms for $ 2 \leq k \leq n $ you have for $ n \geq 2 $
$$ U_n - U_{n-1} < (1/2)^n $$

Comment: please explain last step:(Uk-1-Uk-2)/(Uk+Uk-1) <(Uk-1-Uk-2)/2

Comment: @ChebliFouad Use $ U_n > 1 $ for all $ n> 1$ as shown above.